# ramaze locks uploaded files?

Tags: ruby, rack, ramaze

Has anyone else encountered a file locking issue with Ramaze on Windows? All my uploaded files are being locked (I'm using the upload helper btw).

I'm using 
- Ruby 1.93
- Ramaze-2012.04.14
- Rack-1.4.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Looks like the culprit's this line in ramaze/helper/upload.rb

```
@realfile = File.new(path) #--->this opens the uploaded/saved file, thus locking it
```

I patched my local copy of upload.rb with this --

```
class UploadedFile
    include Ramaze::Traited

    # Suggested file name
    # @return [String]
    attr_reader :filename

    # MIME-type
    # @return [String]
    attr_reader :type

    # Saved file object
    # @return [File]
    attr_reader :realfile #---> expose the variable so we can close it from the caller
```

And then in your caller, simply close the file after you save it, like so...

```
get_uploaded_files.each_pair{|k, v|
    v.save "upload/#{v.filename}"
    v.realfile.close #close the file handle
}
```

I will be submitting a patch soon...